# "Not" "required" combination

Tags: jsonschema

I have defined schema with some properties...Based on condition, i want to disable / enable the properties...Also i need some default behavior too...
Note: "additionalProperties" will be always false.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$ref": "#/TestProperties",
  "TestProperties": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "A": { "$ref": "#/valueDefinition/stringObject" },
      "B": { "$ref": "#/valueDefinition/stringObject" },
      "C": { "$ref": "#/valueDefinition/stringObject" },
      "D": { "$ref": "#/valueDefinition/stringObject" },
      "E": { "$ref": "#/valueDefinition/stringObject" }
    },
    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "A": { "const": "Start" }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "not": { "required": ["C", "D", "E"] },
      "required": ["B"]
    },
    "else": {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "taskType": { "const": "Stop" }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "not": { "required": ["D", "E"] },
        "required": ["B", "C"]
      },
      "else": {
        "not": { "required": ["B", "C"] },
        "required": ["D", "E"]
      }
    }
  },
  "valueDefinition": {
    "stringObject": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^(?!\\s*$).+"
    }
  }
}
```

If my input is

```
{
  "A":"Start",
},
```

it is throwing error saying that mandatory input is missing...

if my input is

```
{
  "A":"Start",
  "B":"xxxx"
}
```

It is displaying as valid JSON...

But if my input is

```
{
  "A":"Start",
  "B":"xxxx",
  "C":"yyyy"
}
```

it is not throwing any error...My expectation is it should not accommodate C

Comment: The `not` keyword inverts the validation result. So by using `not` followed by `required`, you're actually saying "Must not be present". If you want further help, you'll need to tidy up your question so I can see what you're asking clearly =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing like the following will only be valid if all of "C", "D", and "E" are not present.

```
"not": { "required": ["C", "D", "E"] },
```

You want it to be valid if any of "C", "D", or "E" are not present.

```
"not": {
  "anyOf": [
    { "required": ["C"] },
    { "required": ["D"] },
    { "required": ["E"] }
  ]
}
```